# QGIS 2.14 GRASS geoalgorithms don't work?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, polygon-creation, qgis-processing, list

I instaled qgis 2.14 and grass geoalgorithms dont work. Only 160 geoalgorithms and should be 168. MsBox: Missing dependensy, It seems that GRASS is not correctly installed and configured in your system. Please install it before running GRASS algorithms. 
Also v.net geoalgorithms missing.

I reinstall QGIS twice.

I cannot find:
QGIS geoalgorithms:

Smooth: for smoothing line or polygon layers.
Reverse line direction.

there are not on the list...

Comment: Please provide more information about your installation including operating system and method of installation. This sounds like you have a mismatch between GRASS 6 and GRASS 7 (QGIS looking for the other one).

Comment: Windows 10 x64,

Comment: The same problem on other PC, win 10, x64. Last version qgis 2.12.1

Comment: Can you put up a screenshot of Processing->Options->Providers?  In particular, what do your GRASS and GRASS7 Folders look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same issue with versions:

- QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.14.0-1-Setup-x86_64.exe
- QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.14.0-1-Setup-x86.exe

on Windows 7 x64

Used nightly build instead: QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.15.0-9-Setup-x86_64.exe

where the grass integration works fine.

Comment: Thank you, this version works, but still I can not find Smooth: for smoothing line or polygon layers. Reverse line direction.

Comment: same problem, but nightly didn´t work, i have 161 alogrithms

Comment: it is known bug https://hub.qgis.org/issues/12657

Comment: I mixedup all my version qgis

Comment: Grass dont work on qgis 2.12.2, I cannot remove grass 7 i processing toolbox?????