# QGIS 2.16 GRASS geoalgorithms don't work?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, geoprocessing

I have problem again almost like version QGIS 2.14. I did not solve the problem.
[QGIS 2.14 GRASS geoalgorithms don't work?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183134/qgis-2-14-grass-geoalgorithms-dont-work)

I install C:\MinGW and now QGIS grass geoalgorithms don't work?
There is 300 geoalgorithms and I have only 148, what is the problem? 
Is there a solution??
PC Windows 10 x64.

[image]

[image]
[image]

I need other grass geoalgorithms like v.net and others

Comment: Is it that you are missing some algorithms? or that you can't run these 148 you have? Can you attach an error msg? Personally, since I've upgraded beyond QGIS 2.8, all GRASS geo-algorithms stopped working, and I've started using GRASS GUI directly.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199393/grass-tools-not-working-in-qgis-2-14-3-essen-osgeo4w

Comment: Do I need to install OSGEO4W 64-bit, what is this, is this same like QGIS?

Comment: Yes OSGEO4W includes the same QGIS. I wonder why Grass 7 is asking for MSYS. That was cancelled 3 months ago. Do you have processing still  as an external plugin? Only `Grass commands` (which is Grass 6) still needs Msys.

Comment: I do not have problem with proccesing with this 148 geo-algorithms but I need other geo-algorithms. I forgot,  where I can find grass environment? Earlier version had some grass icons, now I cannot find it.

Comment: Well, I have 314 algorithms under GRASS 7. Still wondering why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using OSGeo4W64 setup might be the best solution for you. You have to select QGIS and GRASS (which is GRASS7).

Make sure you delete `C:\users\<username>\.qgis2\python\plugins\processing` if you still have that.

Comment: it's a little strange, on other PC with the same configuration it works fine. I will try, thanks

Comment: On the other PC, do you have the Msys entry under Grass7 in the options menu? What version of processing is listed under Installed plugins? It should be 2.12.99.

Comment: No, I have path C:\MinGW,problem was the same

Comment: Thanks "AndeJ" and "If you do not know- just GIS", I delete C:\users\<username>\.qgis2\ and I install QGIS 2.16 again, now all works fine. This solve my problem. Only I lost all my plugins, I have to install again plugins

Comment: Same problem here. After installing my self written plugin (works fine with 2.14) all grass tools are not working.

Comment: @Pimpel this sounds like a different problem. Please open a new question, including details about your plugin. Is the plugin related to processing or GRASS in any way?